# Git workflow when you cant push or pull

Tags: git, git-workflow, git-patch

This is a [recurring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217187/keeping-repositories-in-sync-without-being-able-to-push-and-pull-commits) question for me, but I'd like to reiterate.

Quickly explain my situation: I am in an environment where I don't have a a git server, nor a shared partition or any common point among the coders. Don't have, will not have, can not have. Period.

I'm trying to come up with a workflow solution, to even in that environment we manage keep our reps at reasonable sync.

The solution I'm trying at the moment uses a discussion group to distribute patches, two main branches and with a seemingly short workflow, follows:

- The branches are `marster` and `yours`
- `master` is the sync branch, which will keep you up to date and track what other deves still don't have of your code.
- `yours` will be your new master, and is where your final code should be. You do not work in `master`.
- everybody sends patches to the discussion list.
- I'm considering that **very** rarely two people will work in the same file.

There are two main actions in the workflow:

**Generate patches:**

1. Got to `yours`
2. Generate patches from `master` (`git format-patch master`)
3. Go to `master`
4. Merge `yours` into `master`
5. **>** Go to `yours`, continue working with `yours`

**Apply patches:**

1. Go to `master` branch
2. Apply received patches
3. Go to `yours` branch
4. Merge `master` into `yours`
5. **>** Continue working with `yours`

If I got it right, this should keep a `master` branch reasonably in sync with everyone else.

Not that the `yours` branch is only to help in keeping track of what other people have or not.

There are a few problems I'm trying to figure if will be too much hassle:

- Order of patches applied?
- How to avoid and detect when someone misses a patch?
- How much problem can be when someone misses a patch?
- Other problems this can generate I haven't even thought of?

Thanks!

Comment: i think it would be way easier to setup a git server accessible by all your team members. afaik `format-patch`/`am` will generate unique commit hashes per repository (different committer). so even if the trees in your repository are the same and history is basically the same, merging/comparing and talking about a particular commit will be a pita (because everybody has different commits, which just happen to evaluate to the same patches). save yourself the hassle and setup a server or get accounts on one of the many hosting sites (github, gitourious, etc.) — they offer private repositories too.

Comment: man.. I *know* that this would be the best. But right now, as I said, I can't (really can't) and to be honest, kind of don't want to - just for the challenge in trying to figure out a way :)

Comment: why can't you? if your project is open source you get even free accounts on the aforementioned sites (plus repo.or.cz). for brain-food: have you had a look at `git bundle`?

Comment: Environment and corporate related issues. Kind of explained in the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217187/keeping-repositories-in-sync-without-being-able-to-push-and-pull-commits/6217273#6217273 , And no, never used ``git bundle``, will take a look! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having one repo with two branches, I would rather have two repo:

- one with only `master` branch in it
- one (cloned from the first) with `master` and `yours`

That way I can:

- merge what I need from `yours` branch to `master` in the '`yours`' repo
- fetch changes from the `master` branch of the `yours` repo into the `master` branch of the `master` repo
- Make a [**incremental bundle**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860166/how-to-synchronize-two-git-repositories/4860455#4860455) from the `master` repo (resulting in one file, easier to communicate)
- mail that one file, along with the SHA1 of the `master` repo

On the receiving end, I would:

- pull from the bundle into the `master` repo
- check its SHA1 (that way, I am sure I didn't miss anything)
- pull the `master` branch from the `master` repo into the `master` branch of the 'yours' repo
- merge what I need from the `master` branch to the `yours` branch.

The idea of having two separate repo is to have one with a SHA1 which can be checked on the receiving end: it must be exactly the same in both sites.

Comment: So, lets say we are 3 working together, we all did some work and sent our bundles to the mailling list.. Wen we come in the morning there will be two bundles for each of us. So we all do: pull from one, pull from another, all into master0. Pull from master0 into masterMine. You are saying this point, all the masterMine's (the three of then) should have same file states (thus same SHA1), regardless of the sequence we did the pulls? (ofc we wont know the final SHA1 until we are finished, but you got the point..)

Comment: @filipo: regarding the SHA1, I was talking about `master0`, not `masterMine` (which include the '`yours`' branch whose content can vary greatly). But even for the `master0` repo, ... according to this answer, no. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632520/apparently-same-commits-give-different-sha1-why/5632680#5632680: the parent of the commits would differ from `master0` repo to another `master0` repo.

Comment: @filipo: The "same SHA1" scheme might work with commits *applied in the same order* (which can be done with a `rebase --interactive` and a good naming convention in the comments of said commits in order to reorder what you just pulled). But this is no trivial solution.